# How pass all properties from wrapper components to child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Assuming we have a wrapper component for `Primeng`'s `Dropdown` component and we want to say to angular that every wrappers properties should go into the sub-component (here is `Primeng`'s `Dropdown`).

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<ss-city-dropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" ... and maybe some other properties of dropdown come here ... BUT they are not mandatory! ></ss-city-dropdown>
```

and use it everywhere that it needed intead of this:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">  <p-dropdown>
```

I tried inherititng it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ss-city-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './city-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class CityDropdownComponent extends Dropdown {
   // here i get some informations about cities and add into dropdown's items.
}
```

But there is a bad thing that it needs to override template. because angular doesn't support inheriting template. So if i do so then it will be awfully on upgrading time.

Now I looking for a better solution. Maybe the `ViewChild` recuses here but I don't have any idea.

Comment: Are you sure you're extending the correct class ? I doubt primeNG will just name its component "Dropdown" ...